# Convergence of the sum if the product converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

How is it possible to show that if the product $\prod_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{|a_j|}<\infty$ converges for $a_j\in \mathbb{C},\;|a_j|<1$ then the following sum converges too $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(1-|a_j|)<\infty$?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Show that $-\log(|a_j|) > 1 - |a_j| > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\prod_{j=1}^n |a_j|^{-1} = (\prod_{j=1}^n |a_j|)^{-1}$ if $\prod_{j=1}^n |a_j| \neq 0$.

If $0 < |a_j| < 1$ , then with $b_j = 1 - |a_j|$ we have $0 < b_j < 1$ and since $1 - b_j < e^{-b_j}$,

$$\prod_{j=1}^n |a_j| =\prod_{j=1}^n(1-b_j) < \exp\left(-\sum_{j=1}^n b_j\right) = \exp\left(-\sum_{j=1}^n (1-|a_j|)\right) $$

If the sum on the RHS diverges to $+\infty$ then the product on the left diverges to $0$. Hence if the product converges, the sum must converge.